# Can WCF service compose of various interfaces?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have to create a WCF service that has five different components.  Each component has an interface and each component has its concrete implementation.  All of these five interfaces combined together makes my application.

I don't know if i should create 5 separate wcf services that the client can call.  Though they are independent and have a single responsibility but I am trying to avoid creating 5 services because it will be an overkill for hosting, deploying and maintenence.  Plus they are pretty light weight.
So I wanted to ask for your opinion and suggestion please?

1. Should I just create a one large interface that implements all of the other five interfaces and a concrete implementation that has functions for all of the interfaces e.g.

   ```
   public interface IMainInterface: IComponent1, IComponent2, IComponent3, IComponent4, IComponent5
    {
        region implementation of IComponent1
            public void CallMethod(){...}
        endregion

       region implementation of IComponent2
       endregion

      //and so on

   }
   ```

**will it not clutter the concrete implementation because implementation of component1..5 will be inside IMainInterface's implementation?**

1. Should I have the five interfaces as the properties of the main interface and create public methods in my implementation that calls the methods of the five implementations e.g.

   ```
   public interface IMainInterface
   {
       public IComponent1 Component1 {get;set;}
       public IComponent2 Component1 {get;set;}
       public IComponent3 Component1 {get;set;}
       public IComponent4 Component1 {get;set;}
       public IComponent5 Component1 {get;set;}
   }
   ```

   It's concerete implementation will be something like:

   ```
   public class Main:IMainInterface
   {
      public void CallComponent1Method()
      {
           Component1.CallMethod();
      }    
   }
   ```

**Which approach would you recommend or is there another approach that I can take?**

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just create a one large interface that implements all of the
>   other five interfaces and a concrete implementation that has functions
>   for all of the interfaces e.g

Yes, a WCF service is defined by it's service contract which represents a single interface. This interface should be decorated with the `[ServiceContract]` attribute and each individual method with the `[ServiceOperation]` attribute.

Comment: wouldn't it clutter the concrete implementation because i will have to add concerete implementation of all of the components into the main component.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, yes it will, but that's how WCF works. If you define another interface (service contract) that's another WCF service.

Comment: because i can create public methods into IMainInterface but the concrete implementation will be pretty empty. we will have separate classes which will hold meaty implementaions of the component1...5 interfaces

Comment: "a WCF service is defined by it's service contract which represents a single interface" is misleading. A WCF service is implemented by a single class which can support an unlimited number of interfaces. Each interface is exposed as an endpoint. An endpoint is defined by a single interface.

Comment: i will be hosting in windows service. how would that work because service host requires the class and interface name

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can have as many interfaces as you wish to. The only thing is that for each interface you will need to define a separate endpoint.

1. Your class must implement all the contracts you want to.
2. All the contracts, which you want to expose, should have to be marked by [ServiceContract] Attribute.
3. For each separate interface you need to define a separate endpoing either declaratively in configuration file or from code.

Comment: Please don’t use signatures or taglines in your posts. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: In that case, if you're looking just to make the files where you've defined your interfaces lighter, just use partial definitions: separate your interface code throughout several files by marking them partial but remember to keep the namespace the same. In this case you will have one interface, and easy to handle code.

Comment: yes but the interface will be huge. shouldnt i have five service hosts instead?

Comment: There are two options to handle this: When I suggest you to go with the first one, you complain about having 5 endpoings, when I suggested the second one - you complained about the interface to be huge. Are you looking for answers for your questions, or just looking a chance to complain ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating 5 interfaces with the ServiceContract and ServiceOperation attributes and having a single class that inherits from the 5 interfaces and contains the definition for their implementation.

I don't see the justification for creating a 6th interface that implements the other 5 unless it has some methods of its own or has some architectural purpose

Comment: the service host will be calling which interface as its service contract?

Answer (score 0):

A WCF service is implemented by a single class. However that class can support an unlimited number of interfaces. Each interface can be exposed as its own endpoint. See [Multiple Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751424%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

So you can absolutely use a single service to implement all 5 interfaces. Just be aware that which service implements which endpoint is abstracted away from a client perspective.  If you’re client needs to talk to three of the interfaces then it will need to create a new proxy/connection to three different endpoints and it should not make any assumptions about the underlying service implementation being shared.